# Finding the Probability of Perfect Squares

Tags: probability, probability-theory, problem-solving

Let $S$ be a set of integers ${1,2,....,n}$
$2$ numbers a and b are selected from $S$.

(Let's solve them both with and without replacement, for a complete reference to someone with the same question In Future)

(I was trying for with replacement)

Find the probability that $a+b$ is a perfect square that also belongs to $S$ (i.e., $a$,$b$,$a+b$ belong to $S$).

My approach

We basically need to solve $root n$ equations as we can have $root n$ possible perfect square from $1....n$

(Using the solution of the equation of two variables adding to a number from permutation, combinations.. and summing them all and then division by $n*n$ to calculate the probability)

But somehow I am lost while calculating the summation..

Also I observed that the solutions to some trivial values too
$n$=$4$ it's 2

$n$=$9$ it's 8

Then it's 15, then it's 24 etc..

(Basically from some trivial n it seems like it's equivalent to the square -1 but it's not true as there are some repetions too, as a's and b 's order won't matter)

Can someone help me with my way or if there exists a better way to solve it, please share..

Thanks..

Ok I got it it's the summation of 3,8,15,24 till √n -1(for replacement case)

Comment: Any thoughts?  Have you, say, computed the answer for modest $n$ to see if you can spot any pattern?  Note: you should specify if you are selecting with or without replacement.

Comment: Added my attempt added the edits thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would think of the following questions:

a) What is the probability that a+b=k for some k? (This is essentially a counting argument, how many pairs (a,b) sum up to k? (for instance, for 7, there are 6 pairs (1,6), (2,5), (3,4), (4,3), (2,5), (6,1)).

b) $\mathbb{P}$($k$ is a perfect square) = $\mathbb{P}(k = 1 \cup k = 4 \cup ... k = \lfloor{\sqrt{n}\rfloor}^2 )$, now what can you say about these events? (It might be easier to think of two cases if you only care about asymptotics: $n$ being a perfect square, and $n$ being one less than a perfect square)

Comment: One is a subset of other? Pardon me, I am solving such problems after a complete 2 years cutoff..

Comment: I meant the events ${k = 1}, {k=4}, ...$. k being a perfect square is equal (in your setting) for it to equal one of the things on the right. (Sure it cannot equal 1 but you can exclude that)

Comment: So that means I have to sum them all, right using the solution from combinatorics?

Comment: Yes, since the events are disjoint.